# Is there an IGMPv1 querier router after all?

Tags: cisco, multicast, igmp, pim

I recently looked into the mechanics of IGMPv1 and v2. Reading RFC 1112, I understand that in IGMPv1, the Querier Router functionality does not exist. All IGMP configured routers in a local network will query the clients.
However, I see that in some vendors' (Huawei and Cisco afaik) implementation of the protocol, the DR chosen by PIM also acts as IGMPv1 querier, while the other routers are silent.

My question is: Is this responsibility of a DR to act as IGMPv1 querier standardized somewhere, maybe in other RFCs? Or is this a pure vendor-based implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PIM-DM RFC3973, section 5.2 IGMP Interactions:

> A PIM-DM Router MAY use the DR Priority option described in PIM-SM
> [14] to elect an IGMP v1 querier